# Binary and Unicode string

Tags: erlang

I have code like this to construct a Binary String

```
[<<"Hello, ", Name/binary>>]
```

Trying to read the `Name` as Unicode. Like this,

```
[<<"Hello, ", Name/utf16/binary>>]
```

Looks like it is an obvious wrong syntax. How can I make this work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `/binary` and functions from [`unicode`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html) module to convert between encodings.

Your question says first that you are constructing the string, then reading it. If constructing, you could write

```
Utf16Name = unicode:characters_to_binary(Name, utf8, utf16),
[<<"Hello, ", Utf16Name/binary>>]
```

EDIT:
Except of course, that's bad: "Hello, " will be UTF8! It should be

```
unicode:characters_to_binary(<<"Hello, ", Name/binary>>, utf8, utf16)
```

or even

```
unicode:characters_to_binary(["Hello, ", Name], utf8, utf16)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.